# Creating array of colors and then using that for Jbuttons?

Tags: java, arrays, swing, jframe

I have the following code which is a JFrame for 25 buttons which each button needs to be assigned randomly a color from the color array. I just put in an array for colors and I am getting an error.

```
import java.awt.event.*; // Needed for ActionListener and ActionEvent
import javax.swing.*; // Needed for JFrame and JButton
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;

public class ColorToggleGui extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

  // This stores all buttons
  JButton[][] buttons;
  //Stores colors
  Color[] colors;

  public ColorToggleGui(String title) {
    super(title);
    setLayout(null);

    //Allocate the size of the array
    colors = new Color[4];

        //Initialize the values of the array
    colors[0] = new Color(Color.red);
    colors[1] = new Color(Color.blue);
    colors[2] = new Color(Color.yellow);
    colors[3] = new Color(Color.green);


    buttons = new JButton[5][5];
    String[] buttonLabels = { "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "","","","","","","","","","","","","","","" };
    for(int row=0; row<5; row++) {
      for (int col=0; col<5; col++) {
        buttons[row][col] = new JButton(buttonLabels[row*3+col]);
        buttons[row][col].setLocation(10+col*55, 10+row*55);
        buttons[row][col].setSize(50,50);
        buttons[row][col].addActionListener(this);
        add(buttons[row][col]);
      }
    }
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setSize(300,450);
  }


  // This is the single event handler for all the buttons
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    System.out.println("Button " + e.getActionCommand() + " was pressed." );
  }

  public static void main(String args[]) {
    ColorToggleGui frame = new ColorToggleGui("Color Toggle");
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }

}
```

The part with the color array I get this error :

```
Error: incompatible types: java.awt.Color cannot be converted to int
```

Why is the error happening? I am also in need of help with a way to use the color array to randomly assign each button with a color from the color array? is there a way I can do this?

Comment: Where you have Colors[0] = new Color(Color.red)) leave out the new Color constructor (ie Colors[0] = Color.red)

Answer (score 1):

use `Color.red` without `new Color()`

```
colors[0] = Color.red;
```

use new constructor if you want to make color from rgb values like

```
colors[1] = new Color(100,100,100);
```

Color constructor has overloaded constructor which accept one integer as a parameter .

```
public Color(int i) {
        // compiled code
}
```

that's why you get error

`Error: incompatible types: java.awt.Color cannot be converted to int`

Answer (score 1):

The constructor for Java Color with a single argument is:

```
Color (int rgb)
```

However, what you did here:

```
colors[0] = new Color(Color.red);
```

You are providing a `Color object` instead of an `int`, hence receiving the error `java.awt.Color cannot be converted to int`.

---

You can simply do this:

```
colors[0] = Color.RED;
```

*Note: It is preferred to use Color.RED instead of Color.red.*

Answer (score 0):

As you asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36001860/982161) before and no one close it:

I give you ***one good answer*** to both questions, and is here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/36004026/982161